# How do you change the tag font size in the repeater-template.php

Tags: php, tags, html

I am very new to Wordpress and I am trying to change the font size in a custom theme from the repeater-template.php. I have the following:

```
<?php the_tags('<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>'); ?>
```

Can I simply add the font size in this way?

```
<font size="6"><?php the_tags('<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>'); ?></font>
```

Thanks for your help,

G.

Comment: You should the size of the font via CSS, only for front end, do not use inline style in markups. Is not easy to maintain and mich more negative results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS file you can easily add it.

```
li {
     font-size: 6px;
}
```

Note: now the font-size of all `li` elements will be 6px

If you want only the tags `li` to be that size it's better to give them a class.

```
<?php the_tags('<li class="tags">', '</li><li class="tags">', '</li>'); ?>
```

and the CSS:

```
li.tags {
     font-size: 6px;
}
```